# Accessing list objects in a dataframe in R using dplyr select

Tags: r, dplyr

I have queried an API using the logic in [this article](https://medium.com/@traffordDataLab/querying-apis-in-r-39029b73d5f1) and I am stuck trying to pull elements of the data from the API response.

I wish to pull the following elements (address_1, address_2, license and issuer) from the data frame but my lack of knowledge in R is preventing me from sub setting the data beyond the first layer of the data frame.

I've tried single square, double square brackets, dollar symbols in multiple permutations but I can't get the syntax right. If someone could help me with this I would be very grateful.

I wish to store the parsed data in a data frame in a structure similar to this

```
    Number       address_1       address_2   license         issuer
 1154328938    7702 E PARHAM RD   STE 304  0101052331    MEDICARE GROUP
```

My code looks as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)

path <- "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?"

request <- GET(url = path,
               query = list(
                 version = "2.0",
                 number = 1154328938
               ))

response <- content(request, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

df <- fromJSON(response, flatten = TRUE) %>% 
  data.frame()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a nested list, so we have to extract that list with either `[[` or use `pluck`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
df %>% 
     select(results.addresses) %>%
     pluck(1, 1, 'address_1')
#[1] "7702 E PARHAM RD" "7702 E PARHAM RD"
```

---

If we check the `str`, it becomes more evident

```
str(select(df, results.addresses))
#'data.frame':  1 obs. of  1 variable:
# $ results.addresses:List of 1
#  ..$ :'data.frame':   2 obs. of  10 variables:
#...
```

Comment: I have modified the O.P to show the desired output. Using dplyr how can I select the fields of interest and store them in a regular data frame?

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
address <- df$results.addresses[[1]][c('address_1', 'address_2')]
address
#        address_1 address_2
#1 7702 E PARHAM RD   STE 304
#2 7702 E PARHAM RD   STE 304

license <- df$results.taxonomies[[1]]['license']
license
#     license
#1 0101052331

issuer <- df$results.identifiers[[1]]['issuer']
issuer
#          issuer
#1 MEDICARE GROUP
```

---

Similarly, using `dplyr::select`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  select(results.addresses) %>% .[[1]] %>% .[[1]] %>%
  select('address_1','address_2')


df %>%
  select(results.taxonomies) %>% .[[1]] %>% .[[1]] %>%
  select('license')

df %>%
  select(results.identifiers) %>% .[[1]] %>% .[[1]] %>%
  select('issuer')
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out but it may not be pretty. I discovered unnest_wider which did the trick.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(httr)
library(jsonlite)
library(purrr)

path <- "https://npiregistry.cms.hhs.gov/api/?"

request <- GET(url = path,
               query = list(
                 version = "2.0",
                 number = 1154328938
               ))

response <- content(request, as = "text", encoding = "UTF-8")

df <- fromJSON(response, flatten = TRUE) %>% 
  data.frame()

providerData <- df %>% 
  select(results.number, 
         results.basic.name,
         results.basic.gender,
         results.basic.credential,
         results.taxonomies) %>%
  unnest_wider(results.taxonomies) %>% 
  rename(Provider_NPI = results.number,
         Provider_Name = results.basic.name,
         Provider_Gender = results.basic.gender,
         Provider_Credentials = results.basic.credential,
         Provider_Taxonomy = desc,
         Provider_State = state) %>% 
  select(-code,-license,-primary)
```